# SqlDependency failed because A SELECT statement that cannot be notified or was provided

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I'm trying to use SqlDependency, And I read articles [Creating a Query for Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v%3Dsql.105)), [Query Notification Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188311(v%3Dsql.105)) from Microsoft.  I double checked many times, it seems all meet what it needs which mentions in articles Here is my code.

```
private void InitialSqlDependency()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string message = string.Empty;

            string query = @"SELECT ModifiedOn FROM [dbo].[ContainerTransactions]";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dr.Read();
                    message = dr[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.Debug("ContainerWatch Dependency Fired!");

        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            _logger.Debug("ContainerWatch Change Fired!");

            this.InitialSqlDependency();
        }
    }
```

However, It always failed to subscribe.  And I see [SqlNotificationInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns `Query` which means `A SELECT statement that cannot be notified or was provided.`  [Here is my debug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX3wV.png)

The SELECT statement is extremely simple, Is there any possible reason causing fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, because `The statement must not reference tables with computed columns`. I use a query below to see computed columns

```
SELECT * FROM sys.computed_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('ContainerTransactions')
```

Therefore, I think I can't use SqlDependency on this table.

Comment: Thanks for returning with an answer - this is valuable. You should be able to accept it as an answer